# Kubernetes Can't connect to database running on host machine

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, microk8s

I have a problem. In my cluster I have a Ruby-On-Rails application which I want to map to the database on the hosted machine (Not containerized). It's a Postgres database, which listens to the following port when I run:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1109/postgres
```

Then I created a service which maps the DB_HOST to the local machine like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external-postgres-svc
  namespace: myapp-nm
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
    protocol: TCP
```

I also added an endpoint:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: external-postgres-svc
  namespace: myapp-nm
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: "10.0.2.2"
    ports:
      - port: 5432
```

And in my configmap I have the following config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: myapp-config
  namespace: myapp-nm
data:
  db_host: "external-postgres-svc.myapp-nm.svc"
  db_port: "5432"
  db_username: "myuser"
  db_password: "mypass"
```

But then when all resources are created and the migration job runs, it never completes. After like 2-3 minutes it crashes and gives the error:

```
connection to server at port 5432 failed: Operation timed out
```

I have added:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

to the `/etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf`, I added:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
```

to the `/etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf`,
so I think it should listen to incoming traffic. I also ran

```
sudo ufw allow 5432/TCP
```

to allow the firewall port on my machine and I checked if the user was correct and it is, so what can be the problem?

I can connect to the database if I am not in the cluster using the

```
ip
port
username
password
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: With your `Service` you are in fact creating a `ClusterIP` for resources that are not in the cluster (look on the `selector`). I'd reckon you should use this instead: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname

Comment: I updated the configs in my question. I think I am getting closer, because it doesn't crash immediately, but now it takes around 2-3 minutes, but still not working :(

Comment: Kubernetes is a clustered environment, but PostgreSQL isn't a clustered database; which node is running the database?  Could you move the database into a StatefulSet inside the cluster?

Comment: The database isn't in any cluster. I wanted the cluster to be stateless, so that's why I moved the database outside the cluster. Someone told me that a database inside a cluster also brings more disadvantages, what is your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

**Error: Operation Timed Out :** indicates that your server failed to issue a complete response within the allowed time period.

**Check below solutions :**

**1)** Check If **/etc directory** owned by another user, /etc directory needs to be set as root user and also open 5432 port. (Add the hostname and IP details of the host in **/etc/hosts**. In the case of a multi-node cluster, the **/etc/hosts** on each machine has to be updated with the details of all cluster nodes).

**2)** Check again that there's no route to the database server because it's being blocked by a firewall. Make sure you set a rule in the firewall to allow the Ruby-On-Rails application to connect.

**3)** Check the setting if you are not doing the connection locally ONLY>, in the **postgresql.conf file**:

```
Connection Settings - #listen_addresses = 'localhost' >>>> This should be = '*' instead of localhost
```

Save the conf and restart the service.

**4) Check Tunnel issue :**
Verify that attributes of the ssh process match what customers provided: Look at the output of ps aux | grep ssh, the relevant part is:
-L number_1:string_or_number_1:number_2 ... KnownHostsFile=/dev/null string_or_number_2

*some_number1: Looker side port number

*string_or_number_1: Database host number or IP address

*number_2: Database side port number

*string_or_number_2: Tunnel server host or IP address

**How to manually set the port:**

**Note :** It is not recommended since it is still possible that the looker set the port back again,instead. Recommend you to open needed ports on the DB.

Create a tunnel through the Looker database connections UI

Update tunnel via the API(PATCH /api/4.0/connections/:connection_name) after it's been created

Set the desired local_host_port

Make sure db_connection and the following fields are set by using API GET /api/4.0/ssh_tunnel/:ssh_tunnel_id or check from go-ssh-sidecar:

*tunnel_id: id of the tunnel

*port: new local_host_port

*host: localhost

**Also check for Improper Tunnel migration:**

The following types of issues may be related to SSH Tunnels on newly migrated K8s

1.Tunnel is not migrated, or tunnels are partially migrated

2.Tunnel is migrated with incorrect information

3.IPs have changed, and are not documented or announced to customers

4.Public keys have changed (specific to migrated tunnels)